# @ Character at the beginning of fonts in CSS

Tags: css, visual-studio

When working with Visual Studio, I always see that `@` character when selecting font family in CSS editor and finally I decided to ask what that is.

Sample image right below :

[The Unknown Character http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/5895/cssunknown.png](http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/5895/cssunknown.png)

**P.s :** It seems like fonts installed only my computer or not general fonts but I am not pretty sure though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are fonts that are appropriate for East Asian languages when the text is displayed vertically.  The preferred traditional reading direction for Japanese, Chinese and Korean.  The glyphs in the font are rotated so that after you create a rotated font, the character displays the right way.

This [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizontal_and_vertical_writing_in_East_Asian_scripts) is excellent, also mentions the @.